# ruby require relative files

Tags: ruby, vim, require

I'm using ruby v1.9.1 in combination with vim and I execute my scripts with:

```
:!ruby "%"
```

my scripts are running fine if I add:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

to add the path of this file to the LOAD_PATH of ruby. If I omit this line my `require` statements to local scripts aren't working anymore.

Is there a way to pass the path of the file to rubys LOAD_PATH? Something like (completly fictional):

```
:!ruby "%" --add-to-load-path
```

I did some research before and stubled upon `require_relative`, but this has the same effect as require and is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-I` option of the ruby executable and write something like the following:

```
:!ruby -I%:p:h. %
```

See `ruby --help` for further information and [file modifiers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%%3a.).

**Edited:** see comments.

Comment: seems to be the right option, but your example only adds my home dir to the LOAD_PATH and not the dir where my script file resides. It might be something like ``:!ruby % -I. "%:p:h"`` but that does not work either (adds nothing to LOAD_PATH).

Comment: You probably want `:!ruby % -I%:p:h` although I can't really test this.

Comment: Could you (or better @lucapette) explain what these options mean? I don't understand the part `%:p:h`.

Comment: I've tested it in my home dire actually ;) So your conclusion is exactly what you was looking for. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @mliebelt please take a look at [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%:.)